# Content inside of button is offset

Tags: html, css

The content I have inside a button is offset in Firefox. I've set the padding and margin to 0 but to no effect. It looks fine in Chrome. Is there anything I can do to fix this?

```css
 body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
 }


 #Group_1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 111.35px;
  height: 43.263px;
  left: 14px;
  top: 13px;
  overflow: visible;
  cursor: pointer;
 }
  
 #Rectangle_1 {
  fill: rgba(255,78,78,1);
  stroke: rgb(112, 112, 112);
  stroke-width: 1px;
  stroke-linejoin: miter;
  stroke-linecap: butt;
  stroke-miterlimit: 4;
  shape-rendering: auto;
 }
 .Rectangle_1 {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: visible;
  width: 111.35px;
  height: 43.263px;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
 }
 #HELLO {
  position: absolute;
  left: 23.749px;
  top: 10.204px;
  overflow: visible;
  width: 65px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
 }
```

```html
<button id="Group_1" onclick="document.title = new Date().toLocaleString()">
 <svg class="Rectangle_1">
  <rect id="Rectangle_1" rx="0" ry="0" x="0" y="0" width="111.35" height="43.263">
  </rect>
 </svg>
 <div id="HELLO">
  <span>HELLO</span>
 </div>
</button>
```

In Firefox it shows:

[image]

If I change it from `button` to `div` it looks fine.

Comment: It's mainly an issue with the border. But the real question is "why do you want to use an SVG element instead of styling the button itself?

Answer (score 0):

Add this browser style reset to your `css`, it's a hack I use and it fixes it for all browsers

```
button {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  line-height: normal;
}
```

Cheers!